# How to create surface to display videos in Tizen native apps?

Tags: tizen, tizen-wearable-sdk, tizen-native-app

I am trying to develop a tizen native app for wearables that displays the video stored in the gear. I don't know how to define the display handle using Evas. Does anybody has any idea how to do it?

Answer (score 0):

Check out Multimedia section at API References — https://developer.tizen.org/dev-guide/2.4.0/org.tizen.native.mobile.apireference/group__CAPI__MEDIA__FRAMEWORK.html

And exactly Display API — https://developer.tizen.org/dev-guide/2.4.0/org.tizen.native.mobile.apireference/group__CAPI__MEDIA__PLAYER__DISPLAY__MODULE.html

Answer (score 0):

Tizen wearables support HTML5. Here is a play and pause example in Tizen Documents.

Link => [HTML5 video and audio element: Playing and Managing Multimedia Content](https://developer.tizen.org/development/tutorials/web-application/w3chtml5supplementary-features/media/html5-video-and-audio-element)

```
<div align="center">
    <h2>Custom Controls : Play & Pause</h2>
    <video id="video" src="media/video_sample.mp4"  width="340" height="220"></video>
    <div>
        <!-- video control : button elements -->
        <button id="v-play" type="button">
            play</button>
        <button id="v-pause" type="button" disabled>
            pause</button>
    </div>
</div>


<script>

    var play_button = document.getElementById("v-play");
    var pause_button = document.getElementById("v-pause");

    play_button.addEventListener("click", function () {
        video.play();  //movie play
    }, false);

    pause_button.addEventListener("click", function () {
        video.pause(); //movie pause
    }, false);

    var video = document.getElementById("video");

    video.addEventListener("play", function () {
        play_button.disabled = true;    //play button disabled
        pause_button.disabled = false;  //pause button enabled
    }, false);

    video.addEventListener("pause", function () {
        play_button.disabled = false;   //play button enabled
        pause_button.disabled = true;   //pause button disabled
    }, false);

    video.addEventListener("ended", function () {
        play_button.disabled = false;   //play button enabled
        pause_button.disabled = true;  //pause button disabled
    }, false);
</script>
```